# How to make multidimentional array from formatted text? PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create a multidimensional array like;

```
$cars = array("brand"=>"toyota","type"=>"suv","color"=>"white");
```

I have a string like;

```
$text = "brand => toyota,type => suv, color => white";
```

How can I create the previous array from this text?

Comment: explode from `','` ?

Comment: Just use explode first for ',' on string and after that '=>' on first explode all result.

Answer (score 4):

It is good to create a small function to do this, so that we can use it in future. Here is my function to do this:

```
function customArray($text) {
   $returnArray = array();
   $explode1 = explode(',',$text);
   foreach ($explode1 as $key => $value) {
     $tempArray = explode('=>',$value);
     $returnArray[trim($tempArray['0'])] = trim($tempArray['1']);
   }
   return $returnArray;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will fulfill your requirements :

```
$text = "brand => toyota,type => suv, color => white";
$cars = array();
$str_explode = explode(",",$text);
$count = count($str_explode);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
  $expl = explode("=>",$str_explode[$i]);
  $cars[$expl[0]] = $expl[1];
}
print_r($cars);
```

**Output :**

`Array ( [brand] => toyota [type] => suv [color] => white )`

Comment: Might be worth also removing all whitespace from the keys.

Comment: @Matt if you will remove only all whitespace than it will be as string not as array.

Comment: @GhanshyamKatriya I'm not quite sure you get what I mean. In addition to your code, remove the spaces in the keys e.g. If you just use that then you will have to access the values like `$cars[' color ']` instead of `$cars['color'];`. Daenu edited your post to remove it in the output, but that edit was incorrect.

Comment: @GhanshyamKatriya The code you have posted may work well but It take more time to run as you have used count() function within for loop. Every time the loop will run it calculate the count() which make it slow. And you have used more variables which are not required as $key and $value that will increase its space complexity.

Answer (score 2):

This just requires you to double explode:

```
$text = "brand => toyota,type => suv, color => white";
$item = explode(",", $text);

$data = array();
foreach($item as $elem):
    list($key, $value) = explode("=>", $elem);
    $data[trim($key)] = trim($value);
endforeach;
```

<sup>*Note: the use of `trim()` on the `$key` & `$value` to remove the white spaces.*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use like that:

```
// your string
$string = "brand => toyota,type => suv, color => white";

// explode with ","
$explodedArr = explode(",",$string);

$newArr = array();
foreach ($explodedArr as $value) {
    // explode value with "=>"
    $explodedInner = explode("=>",$value);
    // also remove the white spaces
    $newArr[trim($explodedInner[0])] = $explodedInner[1]; // using trim() for removing white spaces
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArr);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [brand] =>  toyota
    [type] =>  suv
    [color] =>  white
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another solution using [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and [Anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

```
$text = "brand => toyota,type => suv, color => white";
$cars = array();
$kv = explode(',',$text);
array_walk($kv, function ($item) use (&$cars){
        $kv = explode('=>', $item); 
        $cars[trim($kv[0])] = trim($kv[1]);
        });
print_r($cars);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [brand] => toyota
    [type] => suv
    [color] => white
)
```

Comment: 1) Why you have `&$key` if its of no use. 2) No need to reference your value `&item`

Comment: @Uchiha thanks for pointing out (was too careless). removed those.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$exploded_text = explode(",", $text);
$new_array = array();
for($loop=0; $loop<count($exploded_text); $loop++){
$explode = explode("=>", $exploded_text[$loop]);
$new_array[trim($explode[0])] = trim($explode[1]); 
}
```

Comment: What if string will be like as `brand=>toyota,type=>suv, color => white`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$text = "brand => toyota,type => suv, color => white";

$array1 = explode(',', $text);
$newArray = array();

for ($i=0; $i < count($array1); $i++) { 
    $array2=explode('=>', $array1[$i]);
    $newArray[$array2[0]] = $array2[1];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

HI you can do this way

```
<?php
    $text = "brand => toyota,type => suv, color => white";
    $cars  = array();
    while  (strpos($text,'=>')!== false) {
        $p=strpos($text,'=>');
        if ($p!=false) {
                $i=trim(substr($text,0,$p));
                $text=substr($text,$p+2);
                $p=strpos($text,',');
                if ($p==false) {$p=strlen($text);}
                $v=trim(substr($text,0,$p));
                $text=substr($text,$p+1);
                $cars [$i]=$v;
                }
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format specified following code should work.

```
<?php
$text = "brand => toyota,type => suv, color => white";
$text = explode(',', $text);
$arr = array();
foreach (array_chunk($text, 1) as $chk) {
  $temp = explode('=>', $chk[0]);
  $arr[trim($temp[0])] = trim($temp[1]);

}
echo "<pre>";print_r($arr);echo "</pre>";
```

**Outputs:**

```
Array
(
    [brand] => toyota
    [type] => suv
    [color] => white
)
```

Comment: That's too much complicated and too time consuming